# Demo app label in Ionic

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I am making an application using Ionic framework and I would want to show an small message denoting that the account which the user logged in is a demo (please see image below).
Is possible to do this without modifying all layouts and controllers?
[image]

Comment: yes we can add.....

Answer (score 0):

Yes, possible,

But you should add textbox or textarea and send button on the footerbar.